# how to send time to server from client

Tags: c, server, client, send

In my client.c file I have this code

```
 time_t now;
 struct tm *now_tm;
 int hour;
 int minute;
 int second;

 now = time(NULL);
 now_tm = localtime(&now);
   hour = now_tm->tm_hour;
  minute = now_tm->tm_min;
  second = now_tm->tm_sec;
  printf("%d:%d:%d\n", hour, minute, second");
```

I have already established a connection between client and server and now I am trying to send the local time of client to server. But I am not sure how to send this time to server. Is there any send method in C that accepts 3 integer argument? Could anyone please help me?

Comment: You need to design a protocol, there is nothing built-in.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Could you please tell me more about the protocol? Like if there is any resources that can help me design the protocol?

Comment: Google protobufs are one possibility.

Comment: the posted code does not compile, for several reasons!  Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: OT: regarding: `struct tm *now_tm;`  it is a very poor programming practice to hide a pointer in a typedef.

Answer (score 0):

suggest define a `struct` that contans those three integer values. perhaps via:

```
struct myStruct 
{
    int hour;
    int minute;
    int second;
};
```

declare an instance of the struct and fill in the fields:

```
struct myStruct data;
data.hour   = hour;
data.minute = minute;
data.second = second;
```

caveat: Be sure the server is expecting its' input as an instance of: `struct myStruct` on a specific port at a specific URL

```
//socket():
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
if (sockfd == -1) { 
    perror("socket failed"); 
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); 
} 

// sockaddr_in:
struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET; 

// use server IP4 address in next statement
servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); 

// use server port in next statement
servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);  

//connect():
if (connect(sockfd, (servAddr*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) != 0) { 
    perror("connection failed"); 
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); 
}
```

then

```
if( write(sockfd, data, sizeof( struct myStruct )) != sizeof( myStruct ) )
{
    perror( "write to server failed" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
```

to send the info to the server